# special character at the begin who match with the end from every word [only regex]

Tags: python, regex

what's best solution using regex, to remove special characters from the begin and the end of every word.

> > "as-df-- as-df- as-df (as-df) 'as-df' asdf-asdf) (asd-f asdf' asd-f' -asdf- %asdf%s asdf& $asdf$ +asdf+ asdf++ asdf''"

the output should be:

> > "as-df-- as-df- as-df (as-df) as-df asdf-asdf) (asd-f asdf' asd-f' asdf %asdf%s asdf& asdf asdf asdf++ asdf''"

if the special character at the begin match with the end, remove it

i am learning about regex.
[only regex]

Comment: Seems like there's a mistake in your example input or output... at the end of the first line,
    `+asdf+`
becomes
    `asdf++`
?? Also, what is the exact set of "special characters"? E.g. all non-alphanumeric characters other than space? What constitutes a word boundary? Should multiple matching special characters get stripped, or just one pair?

Comment: Also, there are many dialects of regex languages, so if you want to get an answer that works for you, it would be helpful to specify the dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
a = ("as-df-- as-df- as-df (as-df) 'as-df' asdf-asdf) (asd-f"
     "asdf' asd-f' -asdf- %asdf%s asdf& $asdf$ +asdf+ asdf++ asdf''")
b = re.sub(r"((?<=\s)|\A)(?P<chr>[-()+%&'$])([^\s]*)(?P=chr)((?=\s)|\Z)",r"\3",a)
print b
```

Gives:

```
as-df-- as-df- as-df (as-df) as-df asdf-asdf) (asd-f
asdf' asd-f' asdf %asdf%s asdf& asdf asdf asdf++ asdf''
```

Getting non-identical characters to work is tricker `()`, `[]`, `{}`

Comment: this doesn't do what OP want, ie `asdf-asdf)` must not be altered

Comment: @M42 somewhat fixed, with a caveat

Comment: `(` and `)` are different characters.

Answer (score 1):

For Perl, how about `/\b([^\s\w])\w+\1\b/g`? Note things like \b don't work in all regex languages.

Oops, as @Nick pointed out, this doesn't work for non-identical pairs, like () [] etc.

Instead you could do:

```
 s/\b([^\s\w([\]){}])\w+\1\b/\2/g
 s/\b\((\w+)\)\b/\1/g
 s/\b\[(\w+)\]\b/\1/g
 s/\b\{(\w+)\}\b/\1/g
```

(untested)